ffmpeg piped output producing incorrect metadata frame count
The short version: Using piped output from ffmpeg produces a file with incorrect metadata.
ffmpeg -y -i .\test_mp4.mp4 -f avi -c:v libx264 - > output.avi to make an AVI file using the pipe output.
ffprobe -v error -count_frames -show_entries stream=duration,nb_read_frames,r_frame_rate .\output.avi
The output will show that the metadata does not match the actual frames contained in the video.
Details below.

Using Python, I am attempting to use ffmpeg to compress videos and put them in a PowerPoint. This works great, however, the video files themselves have incorrect frame counts which can cause issues when I read from those videos in other code.
Edit for clarification: by "frame count" I mean the metadata frame count. The actual number of frames contained in the video is correct, but querying the metadata gives an incorrect frame count.
Having eliminated the PowerPoint aspect of the code, I've narrowed this down to the following minimal reproducing example of saving an output from an ffmpeg pipe:
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

video_path = 'test_mp4.mp4'

ffmpeg_pipe = Popen(['ffmpeg',
                     '-y',  # Overwrite files
                     '-i', f'{video_path}',  # Input from file
                     '-f', 'avi',  # Output format
                     '-c:v', 'libx264',  # Codec
                     '-'],  # Output to pipe
                    stdout=PIPE)

new_path = "piped_video.avi"
vid_file = open(new_path, "wb")
vid_file.write(ffmpeg_pipe.stdout.read())
vid_file.close()

I've tested several different videos. One small example video that I've tested can be found  here.
I've tried a few different codecs with avi format and tried libvpx with webm format. For the avi outputs, the frame count usually reads as 1073741824 (2^30). Weirdly, for the webm format, the frame count read as -276701161105643264.
Edit: This issue can also be reproduced with just ffmpeg in command prompt using the following command:
ffmpeg -y -i .\test_mp4.mp4 -f avi -c:v libx264 - > output.avi
This is a snippet I used to read the frame count, but one could also see the error by opening the video details in Windows Explorer and seeing the total time as something like 9942 hours, 3 minutes, and 14 seconds.
import cv2

video_path = 'test_mp4.mp4'
new_path = "piped_video.webm"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
print(f"Original video frame count: = {int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)):d}")
cap.release()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(new_path)
print(f"Piped video frame count: = {int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)):d}")
cap.release()

The error can also be observed using ffprobe with the following command: ffprobe -v error -count_frames -show_entries stream=duration,nb_read_frames,r_frame_rate .\output.avi. Note that the frame rate and number of frames counted by ffprobe do not match with the duration from the metadata.
For completeness, here is the ffmpeg output:
ffmpeg version 2023-06-11-git-09621fd7d9-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavcodec     60. 17.100 / 60. 17.100
  libavformat    60.  6.100 / 60.  6.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  8.101 /  9.  8.101
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_mp4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2022-08-10T12:54:09.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:06.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 567 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 384x264 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:11], 563 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-10T12:54:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] profile High, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
Output #0, avi, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    ISFT            : Lavf60.6.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 384x264 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:11], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-10T12:54:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.17.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[out#0/avi @ 0000018c687f47c0] video:82kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.631060%
frame=  200 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      85kB time=00:00:06.56 bitrate= 106.5kbits/s speed=76.2x    
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.12  size:  3659
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] frame P:80    Avg QP:21.31  size:   647
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] frame B:119   Avg QP:26.74  size:   243
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] consecutive B-frames:  3.0% 53.0%  0.0% 44.0%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] mb I  I16..4: 17.6% 70.6% 11.8%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  1.7%  0.6%  P16..4: 17.6%  4.6%  3.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:71.4%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.3%  0.2%  B16..8: 11.7%  1.4%  0.4%  direct: 0.6%  skip:85.4%  L0:32.0% L1:59.7% BI: 8.3%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] 8x8 transform intra:59.6% inter:62.4%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.5% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 3.5% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 39% 25% 17%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 25% 30%  3%  3%  4%  4%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 20% 16%  6%  8%  8%  8%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] ref P L0: 76.2%  7.9% 11.2%  4.7%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] ref B L0: 85.6% 12.9%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] ref B L1: 97.7%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0000018c68c8b9c0] kb/s:101.19

So the question is: why does this happen, and how can one avoid it?

The compressed video should have the same frame count as the source unless dropping frames. Compression is about using a better compression algorithm or lowering the quality. ffmpeg/ffprobe can be used to count frames

Or as a rough frame count: <duration in seconds> * <fps> so 15 seconds of a video with 30 fps could have around 450 frames

Thanks for the suggestion @LMC! ffprobe reveals similarly odd results. If we ask it to count the frames (which I assume it does by reading each frame sequentially until it runs out), it comes up with the right answer (in this case 200). However, if we also query it for the frame rate and duration, we see that the frame rate is 30 which should give a duration of 200/30 = 6.7 seconds. But the duration from ffprobe (which I assume it takes from the metadata) comes out as 728.23! So again, the metadata somewhere seems to be messed up by the pipe output and I'd love to understand why.

I'm not sure how ffprobe counts frames but I don't think that's part of the metadata but the video itself. Also, why piping ffmpeg output back to python? it could write the file itself.

That's a great question! When I'm writing into a PowerPoint file it's much more convenient for me to grab the video I want, compress it, and insert it into the PowerPoint file directly from the compression pipe (using python-pptx) than it would be for me to make a compressed copy of the file and then use that instead. That would definitely be a functional workaround, but it would seem to me that ffmpeg should be able to write the metadata correctly, even in a pipe.

Seems it's a python issue, not ffmpeg

That's a great find, but I don't think it's the issue here. I can reproduce the problem without Python at all in command prompt using the command ffmpeg -y -i .\test_mp4.mp4 -f avi -c:v libx264 - > output.avi. The resulting file has the same problem as the ones using Python.

If there's a demonstrable issue with ffmpeg (I didn't verify your findings), this seems more suitable to a bug report on ffmpeg bug tracker? https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html

Good point, thanks @Grismar! I think we're definitely at that point after this discussion with @LMC and the further verification therein.

Out of curiosity, have you compared if the outputs of ffmpeg -y -i .\test_mp4.mp4 -f avi -c:v libx264 - > output.avi and ffmpeg -y -i .\test_mp4.mp4 -f avi -c:v libx264 output.avi are identical? In my ffmpegio package, I use AVI format to read multiple streams to numpy arrays, and I vaguely remember that I cannot use the frame count header info because it's piped... but I coded it some time ago to remember the details...

That is, if FFmpeg output is piped, it cannot seek back to fill missing information in the header.

One last comment, .mkv is the only format I know of (that's not raw/streaming format) that can be piped. But it's not supported by PPT, so you might as well create a temp directory, output video there, then read the file to embed...

Thanks for the comments @kesh! The video appears the same between the two, but the metadata in the second one is correct, whereas in the first (piped) one it is not. The inability to seek back to the header would make a lot of sense of why it struggles. I just had a go with .mkv and it actually doesn't have a duration metadata property (as per ffprobe). So it would seem that no matter what, you can get a nice video out with the pipe output (avi, webm, mkv), but there won't be usable metadata (at least at the moment).

I've submitted a bug report here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/11336  but from the sounds of things from @kesh, this may be a fundamental limitation of the pipe system.

As I commented above, it is 100% due to outputting AVI file to a pipe. Check out this part of FFmpeg source code:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c893dcce312af152f21a54874f88576ad279e722/libavformat/avienc.c#L911
Specifically, the if block starting on Line 924 is skipped if you write to a pipe:
if (pb->seekable & AVIO_SEEKABLE_NORMAL) {
  ...
  if (avi->riff_id == 1) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
    avio_wl32(pb, nb_frames);
    ...
  }
}

This cause the piped output to miss some header attributes, including nb_frames as the excerpts above indicates. In addition, some stream attributes are skipped as well (Lines 969-)
So, what you are experiencing is indeed intentional, and it's highly unlikely FFmpeg devs will consider this as a bug.
I was to offer a Python script to fill the nb_frames manually to the retrieved bytearray, but other skipped fields may cause issues anyway. So, I suggest you to just write the AVI file (MP4 file is probably a better choice for PowerPoint nowadays, BTW) to a temp dir and read the output file. Something like this:
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import subprocess as sp
from os import path

video_path = 'test_mp4.mp4'

with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:

   new_path = path.join(temp_dir, "piped_video.avi")


   sp.run('ffmpeg',
          '-y',  # Overwrite files
          '-i', f'{video_path}',  # Input from file
          '-f', 'avi',  # Output format
          '-c:v', 'libx264',  # Codec
          new_path])  # Output to pipe

    from open(new_path,'rb') as f:
        b = f.read()


That's a great find, thanks kesh! As you say, MP4 is definitely better, I was just using AVI here precisely because it can be piped -- but as it turns out, it can't be piped with proper headers!
